# SQL Inner join not working to get change from previous date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following data :

```
TradeDate   Stock   BuySell   DayClose
--------------------------------------
10-Dec-12   ABC        1         11
10-Dec-12   ABC        2         12
11-Dec-12   ABC        1         11.5
11-Dec-12   ABC        2         12.5
11-Dec-12   DEF        1         15
11-Dec-12   DEF        2         16
```

and I want to query on it for a particular date 11-Dec-2012 to get the following output :

```
Stock   Buy     Sell    Mid     Change
--------------------------------------
 ABC    11.5    12.5    12.0    0.5
 DEF    15      16      15.5
```

Since DEF does not have data for the previous date, change should be blank for it.

I have created the following query :

```
Select Stock, 
AVG(CASE BuySell WHEN 1 THEN DayClose END) AS 'Buy', 
AVG(CASE BuySell WHEN 2 THEN DayClose END) As 'Sell', 
Sum(DayClose/2) as 'Mid', 
Sum(Change/2) AS Change

FROM (
select t1.Stock, t1.BuySell, t1.DayClose, Sum(t1.DayClose - t2.DayClose) as Change 

FROM #myTable as t1 inner join #myTable as t2 on 
t1.Stock = t2.Stock

where 
t1.TradeDate = '2012-12-11'  AND 
t2.TradeDate = (SELECT TOP 1 TradeDate FROM #myTable WHERE TradeDate < '2012-12-11' ORDER BY TradeDate DESC)  

GROUP BY 
t1.Stock, t1.buysell, t1.dayclose ) AS P1 GROUP BY stock
```

I created a temp table #mytable for this purpose :

```
drop table #mytable
CREATE TABLE #myTable 
(
    TradeDate datetime,
    stock varchar(20),
    buysell int, 
    dayclose  decimal(10,2)
)
insert into #mytable values ('10-dec-2012', 'abc' , 1, 11)
insert into #mytable values ('10-dec-2012', 'abc' , 2, 12)
insert into #mytable values ('11-dec-2012', 'abc' , 1, 11.5)
insert into #mytable values ('11-dec-2012', 'abc' , 2, 12.5)
insert into #mytable values ('11-dec-2012', 'def' , 1, 15)
insert into #mytable values ('11-dec-2012', 'def' , 2, 16)
```

But I am not able to get the required output, rather getting

```
Stock         Buy         Sell      Mid     Change
--------------------------------------------------------------
abc           11.500000 12.500000   12.00000    1.00
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong. I seem to be lost in here.

Thanks,
Monika

Comment: You need a solution for both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: Please specify how columns Buy, Sell, Mid and change are calculated.

Comment: Hi techdo, Mid = (Buy + Sell ) / 2 for any date and change is calculated as  [ (buy2 - Buy1) + (Sell2 - Sell1) ] / 2

Comment: So in the example, Mid of result 1 should be 12 right?

Comment: MID for 'ABC' is 12.5 in your expected output, shouldn't it be 12?

Comment: You are right. That was a typo. I have edited in the post

Comment: I removed tags I thought irrelevant, explaining the removal in the edit notes. Feel free to put them back if you think they are necessary. (But then it would also be nice to know *how* they are relevant to your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
;WITH T1 as(
SELECT   a.TradeDate
        ,a.stock
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.BuySell = 1 THEN a.DayClose ELSE 0 END) Buy
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.BuySell = 2 THEN a.DayClose ELSE 0 END) Sell
        ,SUM(a.DayClose) / 2 AS Mid
FROM    #mytable a
GROUP   BY a.TradeDate, a.stock
)SELECT  t.*,
        t.Mid - PR.Mid AS Change
FROM    T1 t
LEFT JOIN   
        T1 PR ON 
        PR.TradeDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, t.TradeDate)
AND     PR.stock = t.stock
```

Comment: Aaaah someone that uses CTE's was going to suggest the same techdo. @Monica please mark this answer as accepted and give techdo his recognition.

Comment: @Monica Happy to hear... Namphibian Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Stock, 
AVG(CASE BuySell WHEN 1 THEN DayClose END) AS 'Buy', 
AVG(CASE BuySell WHEN 2 THEN DayClose END) As 'Sell', 
Sum(DayClose/2) as 'Mid', 
Sum(Change/2) AS Change

FROM (
select t1.Stock, t1.BuySell, t1.DayClose, Sum( t1.DayClose - t2.DayClose ) as Change 
FROM #myTable as t1 left join #myTable as t2 on t2.TradeDate = (SELECT TOP 1 TradeDate FROM #myTable WHERE TradeDate < t1.TradeDate ORDER BY TradeDate DESC)   
and t1.Stock = t2.Stock and t1.buysell=t2.buysell 

where 
t1.TradeDate = '11-12-2012'
```

Comment: Hi using your suggestion to use "<=" helps me get data for "def" also, but both change now becomes Zero :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT   a.TradeDate
        ,a.stock
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.BuySell = 1 THEN a.DayClose ELSE 0 END) Buy
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN a.BuySell = 2 THEN a.DayClose ELSE 0 END) Sell
        ,SUM(a.DayClose) / 2 AS Mid
INTO    #temp
FROM    #mytable a
GROUP   BY a.TradeDate, a.stock


SELECT  t.*,
        t.Mid - previousRecord.Mid AS Change
FROM    #temp t
LEFT JOIN   
        #temp previousRecord ON 
        previousRecord.TradeDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, t.TradeDate)
AND     previousRecord.stock = t.stock

DROP TABLE #temp
```

All you have to do now is to select the data for a date.